# Why doesn't AuthorizationOptions use ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-authorization

Recently, I am occasionally facing an error at my AuthorizationPolicyProvider class:

```
public class AuthorizationPolicyProvider : DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider
{
    private readonly AuthorizationOptions options;

    public AuthorizationPolicyProvider(IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        this.options = options.Value;
    }

    /// this method is supposed to be the place where the error arises
    public override async Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        AuthorizationPolicy policy = await base.GetPolicyAsync(policyName);

        if (policy == null)
        {
            policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                            .AddRequirements(new PermissionRequirement(policyName))
                            .Build();
            this.options.AddPolicy(policyName, policy);
        }

        return policy;
    }
}
```

Here is some of the error stack:

```
    System.NullReferenceException:
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.set_Item (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationOptions.AddPolicy (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization, Version=3.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
.....
```

Based on the error stack, I have a guess that the error might be caused by multithreads problem of Dictionary, because the implementation of AuthorizationOptions use Dictionary, instead of ConcurrentDictionary:

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides programmatic configuration used by <see cref="IAuthorizationService"/> and <see cref="IAuthorizationPolicyProvider"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public class AuthorizationOptions
    {
        // Why dont they use ConcurrentDictionary here
        private IDictionary<string, AuthorizationPolicy> PolicyMap { get; } = new Dictionary<string, AuthorizationPolicy>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
....
        public AuthorizationPolicy GetPolicy(string name)
        {
            if (name == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
            }

            return PolicyMap.ContainsKey(name) ? PolicyMap[name] : null;
        }
    }
}
```

And I follow the guide of Microsoft in: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and add the custom AuthorizationPolicyProvider as Singleton:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, AuthorizationPolicyProvider>();
```

So do you guys know why dont they use ConcurrentDictionary, is it a bug from Microsoft, or because of my implementation, thank you.

Comment: Could you please post your `AuthorizationOptions.cs` class?

Comment: Hi Plamen, it's an implementation of Microsoft, you can find it here : https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/AuthorizationOptions.cs

Answer (score 0):

Do it yourself :

```
public class DynamicAuthorizationPolicyProvider : DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider
{

    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthorizationPolicy> DynamicPolicyMap { get; } = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthorizationPolicy>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public DynamicAuthorizationPolicyProvider(IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public override async Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        AuthorizationPolicy policy = await base.GetPolicyAsync(policyName);

        if (policy == null)
        {
            return DynamicPolicyMap.GetOrAdd(policyName, CreateDynamicPolicy);
        }
        return policy;
    }

    private AuthorizationPolicy CreateDynamicPolicy(string policyName)
    {
            
    }
}
```